# Run provisioning scripts per project in Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, bash, laravel

I searched around for and I couldn't find an answer, probably because Homestead is so new, but I was wondering: In Laravel Homestead, is there a way to have 'vagrant up' run through provisioning scripts for each project defined in the 'Homestead.yaml' file?

To be clear, I have a project defined in Homestead.yaml that has a bash script that I need to run to ease setup. Is this possible somehow?

Perhaps, in the project root, have another Homestead.yaml file that defines any bash scripts to be run when initializing the vagrant box?

Or maybe a custom-written bash script that runs a .sh file in each project's root directory? Any ideas?

Comment: if my answer worked for you, it would help the community if you marked it as the answer to your issue

Answer (score 4):

Following from isimmons answer, here is how I actually created a working project specific setup script for **Homestead v2** and an earlier version for **Homestead v1**

### Intro:

I keep all my projects in a projects folder outside my homestead repo in a folder called projects:

**Folder Structure**:

- /outside-homestead/projects/myapp1,
- /outside-homestead/projects/myapp2,
- etc...

Within each project I have a folder I call provision with a sub folder bash among others
/outside-homestead/projects/myapp1/provision/bash

Within each bash folder I place a setup.sh file with my commands:

- outside-homestead/projects/myapp1/provision/bash/setup.sh

---

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "==============================================="
echo "Project - DEPLOYMENT"
echo "==============================================="
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Project - Going down for maintenance."
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
php artisan down
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Project - Down for maintenance."
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Project - Composer is installing project."
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
composer install
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Project - Composer is updating project."
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
composer update
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Project - Composer is updating class autoload."
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
composer dump-autoload
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Project - Application is being optimized."
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
php artisan optimize
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Project - Artisan is migrating DB."
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
php artisan migrate --seed --force
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Project - Coming up from maintenance."
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
php artisan up
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Project - LIVE."
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
```

Naturally you can get as simple or complicated with this deployment file as you want depending on the complexity of your project.

Create 2 files in the scripts folder of your homestead installation: project_setup.sh and server_setup.sh. The file project_setup.sh is for calling and running the project specific setup.sh files.

### scripts/projects_setup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

cd $4
dos2unix $3
/bin/bash $3
```

The file server_setup.sh is for running general commands that all development projects need, things such as XDebug enabling, nginx upload settings, database creation/settings (v1 only) and php configs.

### scripts/server_setup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "============================================"
echo "Homestead - PROVISIONING"
echo "============================================"
env VAR='() { :;}; echo Bash is vulnerable!' bash -c "echo Bash is safe"
sudo apt-get update -y -q
sudo apt-get install php5-intl -y -q
echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo "Homestead - Enabling XDebug."
echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo '\n '                          >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000'      >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.remote_mode=req'       >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1' >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp'   >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=1' >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1'       >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=0'    >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.max_nesting_level=400' >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM'       >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.default_enable=1'      >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.cli_color=1'           >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.scream=0'              >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo 'xdebug.show_local_vars=1'     >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo '\n '                          >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
echo "------------------------------------------"
echo "Homestead - Enabled XDebug."
echo "------------------------------------------"

etc....
```

Next, you want to make sure your files are called as you enter vagrant/homestead up. To do so, you will need to slightly modify scripts/homestead.rb . Look for these lines:

```
# Configure All Of The Server Environment Variables
if settings.has_key?("variables")
  settings["variables"].each do |var|
    config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
        s.inline = "echo \"\nenv[$1] = '$2'\" >> /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf && service php5-fpm restart"
        s.args = [var["key"], var["value"]]
    end
  end
end

# Update Composer On Every Provision
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
  s.inline = "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update"
end
```

After this section add this code

```
# Custom Server provisioning
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = "dos2unix /vagrant/scripts/server_setup.sh"
end
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = "bash /vagrant/scripts/server_setup.sh"
end

# Custom Project provisioning
settings["sites"].each do |site|
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
      s.path = "./scripts/project_setup.sh"
      s.args = [site["map"], site["to"], site["provisionScript"], site["appHome"]]
  end
end
```

Homestead 2 has the option of adding custom scripts in an "after" file at [HOME].homestead\after.sh . This file is for calling scripts AFTER the entire homestead provisioning process is over and will thus be run after server_setup.sh and the looped project_setup.sh have **already been run**. Another difference between v1 & v2 is in the Homestead.yaml file with regard to databases. Instead of placing database creation code in the server_setup you simply add a list of databases in the Homestead.yaml:

```
databases:
    - homestead
    - project1db
    - project2db
```

For both Homestead 2 & Homestead 1 the rest of the Homestead.yaml is the same. To enable this "customization", add these 2 variables to the sites section of your Homestead.yaml:

- provisionScript
- appHome

The **provisionScript** variable is the full path of your setup.sh file within vagrant, not on your desktop host. This keeps things OS independent which is the purpose of VMs anyway.

The **appHome** variable is the full path of your project. You want this variable outside of your deployment script because the location of your deployment script should be server independent and this variable is Homestead specific. Basically, you should be able to copy the contents of setup.sh to say Laravel Forge's deployment script editor (and such) without the need to change the contents (much).

The location of Homestead.yaml is version specific:

- Homestead v2 => [HOME].homestead\Homestead.yaml
- Homestead v1 => /Homestead.yaml

### Homestead.yaml

```
sites:
- map: vm.myapp1.local
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/myapp1/public
  provisionScript: /home/vagrant/Code/myapp1/provision/bash/setup.sh
  appHome: /home/vagrant/Code/myapp1

- map: vm.myapp2.local
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/myapp2/public
  provisionScript: /home/vagrant/Code/myapp2/provision/bash/setup.sh
  appHome: /home/vagrant/Code/myapp2
```

Now when you vagrant/homestead up, Vagrant will run the server_setup.sh once and loop project_setup.sh to call your project specific setup.sh files.

You'll see the output as vagrant runs. So, for easy reading and detailed documentation you want to demarcate where each activity starts. A good tutorial to bookmark, and from which I borrowed heavily, is: http://scotch.io/tutorials/php/getting-started-with-laravel-homestead

Comment: Where is the file `homestead/scripts/homestead.rb` ?

Comment: `homestead/scripts/homestead.rb` is the correct reference assuming you cloned/downloaded homestead into the `homestead` folder

Comment: Where can I found official documentation about provisionScript ?

Answer (score 1):

In scripts/homestead.rb it appears you have access to the site map from homestead.yaml

With the following yaml file 'sites' section

```
sites:
    - map: testapp.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/testapp/public
    - map: testapp2.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/testapp2/public
```

Taking from how the 'Configured Nginx Sites' section loops through the 'map' and 'to' in homestead.yaml, you can pass these values off to your own script.

```
#test calling script and sending the site domain and dir path as args
    settings["sites"].each do |site|
      config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
          s.path = "./scripts/foo.sh"
          s.args = [site["map"], site["to"]]
      end
    end
```

scripts/foo.sh

```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "site $1 is mapped to $2"
```

result:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:/Users/lotus/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20140525-3876-odm1f6.sh
==> default: site testapp.dev is mapped to /home/vagrant/Code/testapp/public
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:/Users/lotus/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20140525-3876-14jbkwm.sh
==> default: site testapp2.dev is mapped to /home/vagrant/Code/testapp2/public
```

I'm not familiar enough with shell scripting to provide any further info but it seems you could work with this as a starting point.

UPDATE: You can also add your own args to the site section and use them the same way

```
sites:
    - map: testapp.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/testapp/public
      foo: "hello from foo"
    - map: testapp2.dev
      foo: "hello from foo 2"
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/testapp2/public
```

Then pass through s.args = [site["map"], site["to"], site["foo"]] in homestead.rb and echo them as arg 3 "$3" in foo.sh This might be helpful for doing something on a per site basis.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Let me see if I can make this work. :) I'll post my results here and mark the answer as accepted if so.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go !

```
homestead halt && homestead up --provision
```